# WebSocket only connects in debug, gets stuck in connecting otherwise

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

When trying to connect to a WebSocket server using typescript and a function as simple at this:

```
export class WebRTCConnection {

  private ws: WebSocket;

  //...

  public initWebSocket(url: string) {
     this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
  }

  //...
}
```

The WebSocket will get stuck in the `CONNECTING` state.

No other properties are set on the WebSocket object.

When I put a breakpoint on the `new WebSocket(url)` line in my browser and step over it the WebSocket will connect fine.

This problem has appeared in every browser I have tested (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).

Why is the WebSocket not connecting in a normal runtime? It will work using the same url as in the code when creating a WebSocket from the console.

Answer (score 0):

When do you call the `initWebSocket` function compared to initialisation? It could be as simple as, when you've put the break point you are allowing other processes to complete in time. So a (poor) solution would be to put the initialisation in a `timeout`?

Comment: The function is called after the DOMContentLoaded event (this project does not use jquery). The page should be ready then.